# Check for broken links using java code and link is not getting redirect

Tags: htmlunit, broken-links

```
 This code will check my link is broken or not and validateWebResourceUrl method will return 0 status .even if i get 200 status my link couldn't redirect to mozilla firefox when i call my api call.Below code will show u my api cal.


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/validate/fburl")
    public ModelAndView validateFbLink(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="key", required=true) String key ,@RequestParam(value = "link") String link, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView jsonmodel = new ModelAndView("rest/model");

        jsonmodel.addObject("model", httpFrameBreakChecker.validateHttpLink(link, key));
        return jsonmodel;
    }
```

This api call will go to check the link is broken or not ,if not it will go to redirect.I am trying to find the broken links and i am getting status 200 for that link but that link is not redirecting.Below is my code.

```
    package org.ednovo.gooru.util;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse;

    @Component
    public class HttpFrameBreakChecker extends LinkChecker {

        @Override
        public Integer validateHttpLink(String resourceUrl, String key) {

            Integer status = null;
            status = validateWebResourceUrl(resourceUrl, getPageTesterPath());
            putResourceStatus(status, key);

            return status;

        } 

        public synchronized Integer validateWebResourceUrl(String webURL, String pageTesterURL) {

            WebClient webClient = null;
            WebResponse webResponse = null;

            try {
                webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
                webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
                webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
                webResponse = webClient.getPage(webURL).getWebResponse();
                int i = webResponse.getStatusCode();
                logger.info(i+"");
                if (webResponse.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                    return null;
                }
                String urlToCheck = webURL + pageTesterURL;

                // Now check if the page has a frame breaker.
                webResponse = webClient.getPage(urlToCheck).getWebResponse();
                int status = webResponse.getStatusCode();
                logger.info(status+""+"frame");
                String pageURL = webResponse.getWebRequest().getUrl().toString();
                int validationStatus = (urlToCheck.equals(pageURL) && status == 200) ? 0 : 1;
                logger.info(validationStatus+ " return statement of validateWebResourceUrl ");
                return validationStatus;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.error("ERROR : Unable to start web driver : " + exception.getMessage());
                return null;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (webClient != null) {
                        webClient.closeAllWindows();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void commitPage() {

            if (resources.size() > 0) {
                String resourcesString = getxStream().toXML(resources);
                postData(getApiPath(), "/resource/urls/update/frameBreaker/" + getGlobalJobKey(), resourcesString);
                postData(getSearchApiPath(), "/search/resource/update/index/" + getGlobalJobKey(), resourcesString );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "FB";
        }
    }

   And Below code will show you the LinkChecker class.

package org.ednovo.gooru.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.restlet.data.Form;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;



public abstract class LinkChecker extends BaseComponent {

    private int pageSize = 100;

    private Map<String, String> configSettings;

    private XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

    protected Map<Integer, List<String>> resources = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    private String listResponse = null;

    private Map<Long, String> resourceUrls = null;

    public final synchronized void execute() {
        reset();
        ClientResource configResource = null;
        Representation representation = null;
        try {
            configResource = createClientResource(getApiPath() + "/config-settings");
            representation = configResource.get();
            String settingsText = representation.getText();
            configSettings = (Map<String, String>) xStream.fromXML(settingsText);
            if (isLinkCheckerSchedulerEnabled()) {
                run();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error(exception.getMessage());
        } finally {
            releaseClientResources(configResource, representation);
        }
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {

        reset();

        int page = 0;

        while (true) {
            ++page;
            listResponse = null;
            resourceUrls = null;

            final int currentPage = page;

            ClientResourceExecuter clientResourceExecuter = new ClientResourceExecuter() {

                @Override
                public void run(ClientResource clientResource, Representation representation) throws Exception {

                    reset();

                    clientResource = createClientResource(getSearchApiPath() +"/search/resource-url-check?category="+getType()+"&pageSize="+pageSize+"&format=xml");

                    representation = clientResource.get();

                    listResponse = representation.getText();

                    if (listResponse != null || listResponse.length() > 1) {

                        try {

                            resourceUrls = (Map<Long, String>) xStream.fromXML(listResponse);

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            logger.error("Conversion of json to list failed in " + getType() + " validation");
                        }

                        logger.warn("Validating " + getType() + " Urls of Page : " + currentPage + " with size : " + (resourceUrls != null ? resourceUrls.size() : 0));

                        validateResourceUrls(resourceUrls);
                    }

                }
            };

            clientResourceExecuter = null;
            listResponse = null;

            if (resourceUrls == null || resourceUrls.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (getType().equals("HTTP") && page >= 5) {
                break;
            }else if (getType().equals("FB") && page >= 1) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public Integer validateHttpLink(String link, String key) {

        URL url = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        Integer responseCode = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(link);
            connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode != 200) {
                logger.error("Url Checker validation fails  for resource : " + link + " : " + responseCode);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.error("Error in link checker : " + link + " Message : " + e.getMessage());
            return 404;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error in link checker : " + link + " Message : " + e.getMessage());
            return 404;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error in link checker : " + link + " Message : " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (httpConnection != null) {
                    httpConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
        return responseCode;
    }

    protected void postData(String path, String url, String data) {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.add("data", data);
        createAndRunClientResource(path, url, form);
    }

    public void validateResourceUrls(Map<Long, String> resourceUrls) throws Exception {

        if (resourceUrls.size() > 0) {

            Iterator<?> iterator = resourceUrls.entrySet().iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry<Long, String> entry = (Map.Entry<Long, String>) iterator.next();

                String resourceUrl = entry.getValue();
                if (getType().equals("FB")) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(900);
                }
                logger.debug("Validating " + getType() + " url - " + resourceUrl);
                Integer status = validateHttpLink(resourceUrl, entry.getKey()+"");

                putResourceStatus(status, entry.getKey()+"");
            }

            commitPage();
        }

    }

    public void commitPage() throws Exception {

        if (resources.size() > 0) {
            String resourcesString = getxStream().toXML(resources);
            postData(getApiPath(), "/resource/urls/checker/update/" + getGlobalJobKey(), resourcesString);
            //postData(getSearchApiPath(), "/search/resource/update/index/" + getGlobalJobKey(), resourcesString);
        }

    }

    public void putResourceStatus(Integer status, String resourceId) {
        if (status == null) {
            status = -99;
        }
        List<String> resourceIds = null;
        if (resources.containsKey(status)) {
            resourceIds = resources.get(status);
        } else {
            resourceIds = new ArrayList<String>();
            resources.put(status, resourceIds);
        }
        resourceIds.add(resourceId);
    }

    public void reset() {
        resources.clear();
    }

    public boolean isLinkCheckerSchedulerEnabled() {
        if (configSettings != null && configSettings.containsKey("urlChecker.scheduler.enabled")) {
            return configSettings.get("urlChecker.scheduler.enabled").equals("true") ? true : false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public abstract String getType();

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public XStream getxStream() {
        return xStream;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }
}
```